# How can I copy and rename files with the same file name

Tags: solaris

I have a directory structure that contains a number of files which are named the same as in:
  dir1/test
  dir2/test
  dir3/test
I want to find each test file and copy it to another directory with a unique (arbitrary) file name so I can analyze the data they contain. 
There could be a large number of these similarly named files contained several layers deep in the directory structure. I can use find to locate the files but the renaming (using find) is alluding me. 
Can anyone provide guidance on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- **source_dir** is root directory form where you want to search the files.
- **destination_dir** is destination directory to where you want to copy or move your files
- ***.doc** is your file name or file pattern to search for.

You can **copy** files with following command! note that `--backup=numbered` will create numerically increased suffixed file if file with that name is already in destination directory.

```
find /source_dir -type f -name *.doc | xargs -I '{}' cp --backup=numbered {} /destination_dir
```

You can **move** files with following command! note that `--backup=t` will create numerically increased suffixed file if file with that name is already in destination directory.

```
find /source_dir -type f -name *.doc | xargs -I '{}' mv --backup=t {} /destination_dir
```

You can also consider using these commands with **sudo** if you might have in search destination matching files belonging to other user.

If you want verbose output of these commands add add -v after `--backup=numbered` or `--backup=t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the / in the path with another character and use that as the new file name:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /dir*/*
do
    cp "$f" "${f//\//.}"
done
```

Comment: Can I integrate your answer into a find command? As in, find . -name FNAME -exec bash -c 'for f in {} do; cp {} "$f" "/tmp/somedir/${f//\//.}" ; done \;. I tried it and received modifier failed. Should this work?